# Angular 6 Convert Json data to an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular6

[image]

the data im getting from server comes in this format i want it to come in a form of an Object.

```js
public getOrder(): Observable < ORDERS > {
  return this._http.get < ORDERS > (`${this._apiBase}/charts/list/ORDERS/`);
}
```

here how im getting the data from server.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this._dashService.getOrder().subscribe(order => {
    this.orders = order;
    console.log(this.orders);
  })
}
```

Comment: Is the issue that the response you get is a string rather than an object?

Comment: yes that the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that the your service is not setting the *Content-Type* property of the http header to *application/json*.

If you own the service, you could try to set the header property of the response.
If you are not able to change it, you can try the `JSON.parse()` method.

Comment: this works but it requires me to  replace Observable<ORDERS> with Observable<any>

Comment: you can cast it in typescript:
`let result = this._http.get < ORDERS > ('${this._apiBase}/charts/list/ORDERS/');
return JSON.parse(result) as ORDERS;`
I am getting the feeling that your format is not correct. Are you sure the result from the service can map to the ORDERS type?

Comment: @muzijack What does ORDERS look like?

Comment: export interface ORDERS {
    dc: number;
    name: string;
    type: string;
    category: string;
    dc_id: string;
    dc_name: string;
    series: Array<Series>;
  }

Comment: I think you should use `ORDERS[]` instead of `ORDER`
Your data contains multiple ORDER sets.
Make the return type `Observable<ORDERS[]>` and you should be fine. You can even drop the `JSON.parse()` code.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick!

```js
public getOrder(): Observable < ORDERS > {
  return this._http.get(`${this._apiBase}/charts/list/ORDERS/`).map((res) => <ORDERS>res.json())
}
```

Comment: this gives an error map function is not provided in this response only subscribe

Comment: @muzijack did you  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'  ?

Comment: pls refer this https://github.com/ravi7mech/yify_app/blob/master/src/providers/yify-movies/yify-movies.ts

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your response using `json` method.

```
public getOrder(): Observable < ORDERS > {
  return this._http.get(`${this._apiBase}/charts/list/ORDERS/`)
                   .map((res) =>res.results as ORDERS[] || [])
                   .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error));
}
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.

Comment: you have to import operator from rxjs.add following import to your code...import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: @AravindaMeewalaarachchi there is typo in your post ! res.json() not response.json()